# Create a directory on the local file system using SQL Developer and PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have some PL/SQL for creating an excel spreadsheet from a set of tables. which I am running using SQL Developer. On my local machine (where the database is also installed) it works fine, but on our test environment where the database is on a different machine (that I don't have access to), it doesn't.

The relevant PL/SQL statements that are failing are:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY TEST_DIR AS 'c:\TEST'
/ 
...
v_fh := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(upper(v_dir),v_file,'w',32767);
...
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_fh,'<ss:Row>');
```

I know the issue is because `CREATE DIRECTORY` creates "an alias for a directory *on the server file system*" ([Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-DIRECTORY.html)) , rather than the local one. How can I create the file on the local machine? Is this something that is possible using SPOOL?

Comment: "*How can I create the file on the local machine*" - you can't. At least not with PL/SQL

Comment: you cannot do that.  Create it on the server then copy it.

Comment: I don't have access to the server to do that. I suspected as much though. But I know I can generate files locally using SPOOL - I've done that before to create CSV files. So it might be possible to do the same here also?

Comment: You can create a SPOOL file locally using the capabilities of you scripting language, but NOT with SQL or PLSQL.  That is you cannot use utl_file. You must return a result set to your script and spool it from there.

Comment: If it's mounted and visible from the db, you can write on a shared directory; if you can populate a table, with your result, you can then use Sql Developer to export that table on Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CREATE DIRECTORY and UTL_FILE is only on the server where Oracle database instance is running.